# Delete specific row in SQLite Database

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

So, in my app you have to add eletrical equipment to every room in the house so it can measure how much energy you spend and etc.

What I want is when I click the button to remove a specific equipment, that equipment will be deleted from the database where it was stored, and this would be with only the name of the equipment as entry.

I have a code but when I hit the remove button the app kinda crashes and goes back to the home activity.

Can someone help pls?

That's the button:

```
button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            button2.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            tableLayout1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            imageView1.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            textView12.setVisibility(View.GONE);

            DatabaseOperations DOP;
            String equipamento;
            equipamento = textView12.getText().toString();

            DOP = new DatabaseOperations(CTX);
            Cursor CR = DOP.getUserInfo(DOP, equipamento);
            CR.moveToFirst();
            DOP.deleteEquip(DOP, equipamento);


            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"O equipamento foi removido com sucesso.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

        }
    });
```

And this is the class:

```
public Cursor getUserInfo (DatabaseOperations DOP, String equipamento){
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = DOP.getReadableDatabase();
    String selection = TableData.TableInfo.EQUIPAMENTO +" LIKE ?";
    String coloumns[] = {TableData.TableInfo.POTENCIA, TableData.TableInfo.QUANT, TableData.TableInfo.HORAS, TableData.TableInfo.SIMULT};
    String args [] = {equipamento};
    Cursor CR = SQ.query(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, coloumns, selection, args, null, null, null);
    return CR;
}

public void deleteEquip(DatabaseOperations DOP, String equipamento){
    String selection = TableData.TableInfo.EQUIPAMENTO;
    String args[] = {equipamento};
    SQLiteDatabase SQ = DOP.getWritableDatabase();
    SQ.delete(TableData.TableInfo.TABLE_NAME, selection, args);
}
```

Comment: Hard to help without knowing why the app crashes. Edit your question to include the logcat please

Comment: You do have two databases instances open... There is no obvious reason you need the user information in order to delete a row

Comment: if I were you, I'd prefer the use **Sugar ORM** to prevent the headache of dealing with queries.

Comment: `the app kinda crashes` ... this description of your issue is worth **nothing**. Post your (full) logcat, instead.

Comment: Try changing `String selection = TableData.TableInfo.EQUIPAMENTO;` to `String selection = TableData.TableInfo.EQUIPAMENTO + "=?";`

Answer (score 0):

@EngWatt this code is in the DBHelper Class you will need to change the rowid to reflect the name of the item you want to delete. I assume that is equipamento 
We hope you have a MVP design to make all this easy

```
    /* Delete a record from database table named "TABLE_INFO" */
/* based on the selected records id in Col_ID*/
public void deleteDBRow(String rowid){

    db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.delete(TABLE_INFO, Col_ID + " = ?", new String[] { rowid });
    db.close();
    return;
}
```